# Open Image Error Python

Tags: python, file-io, io, ioerror

*Hello* everyone I'm trying to open a image that i have downloaded through a link. I searched on the site and found something very useful and implemented that into my code.

```
*if* __name__ == "__main__":
    import urllib
    droste = urllib.urlopen("http://is.gd/cHqT")
    with open("droste.png", "wb") as imgFile:
        imgFile.write(droste.read())
    print "Got it!"
    droste = Image.open("droste.png")
    while droste:
        droste.show()
        droste = reveal(droste)
        if droste:
            open("droste.png", "wb").write(droste)
            droste = Image.open("droste.png")
```

The error occurs on the 7th line `"droste = Image.open("droste.png")"`. I'm getting a IOError: cannot identify image file. I know the image has been downloaded because the codes runs great until that particular line and the line  `print "Got it!"`  actually confirms that its been downloaded. I don't know if I need to specify the path of the image file in the parameter in the open instead the of image name. Or maybe I need to check the path of the file. Please help.

Comment: In what way is that C#?

Comment: This for sure is no C# code...

Comment: This looks more like python.

Comment: oh sorry i was thinking of something else yes its pyhton i'll change the title

Comment: If you're getting a IOError: cannot identify image file it'd more likely coming from the `Image.open("droste.png")` since until then it just treated as raw data by the file `read` and `write` methods. See if you can open the downloaded file in an image editor to verify whether it's OK or not.

Comment: Works OK for me after adding a `from PIL import Image` near the top.

Comment: wow i have that same line at the top and it still doesn't work I'm using pythonAnywhere to code this. do you know how I can find the directory that the image is in

Comment: Works on my end as well except for the 'reveal' is not defined. _edit:_ after adding the import.

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something stupid, but might imgFile.close() help? before opening it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is functional. The problem is how you are running it. You mentioned in your comments that you are using PythonAnywhere. PythonAnywhere is not set up to do anything graphical. It will download the image into the correct directory, but PIL will not function correctly with PythonAnywhere.

Try the following code to test this.

```
import urllib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    droste = urllib.urlopen("http://is.gd/cHqT")
    with open("droste.png", "wb") as imgFile:
        imgFile.write(droste.read())
    print "Got it!"

    print "Now lets test if it really exists..."
    try:
        with open("droste.png", "rb") as imgFile:
            pass
        print "There were no errors so the file exists"
    except:
        print "ERROR: image was not saved properly!"
```

If you start up a BASH session with PythonAnywhere, you will see that the file droste.png exists, and you can download it to your computer and view it. Your program is OK.

If you really want to use your program, or get serious about python programming. You really should install Python locally to your computer. If you want to keep your code in the cloud, then use dropbox, github, or bitbucket. PythonAnywhere has uses, but normally you will just want to have python on your computer.